# WunderList Sliding Drawer Issue; sliding layer doesn't overlay

Tags: android, android-studio, slidingmenu, wunderlist

I am trying to use wunderlist's sliding-layer-lib, however I am having an issue where the layer that slides in doesn't overlay the main content layer. Am I missing something to fix this? [image]

The following is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"             android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nanopay.loyalty_app_android.Activities.TempActivity">


<com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
    xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    slidingLayer:stickTo="left"
    slidingLayer:changeStateOnTap="true"
    slidingLayer:shadowSize="8dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#14ad8f">

      .......

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOpen"
    android:text="Open"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp" />

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="25sp">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/OFFERS"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="201dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/PAYMENT"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/awesomepager1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a background color on the `com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer`

Comment: This changes the color of the screen even without opening the slider